# SQLite turn specific row columns into additional columns and do inner join for each of those columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, dynamic, row, multiple-columns

Sorry for the weird title but I don't know how to phrase it better.

I have table `Attributes`:

```
id|Name
-------
1 |att1
2 |att2
3 |...
```

table `Product` :

```
id|Name
-------
1 |Pro1
2 |Pro2
3 |Pro4
```

and table `ProductAttribute` :

```
id|productId|attributeId|value
------------------------------
1 |1        |1          |val11
2 |2        |1          |val21
3 |2        |2          |val22
4 |...
```

---

I want to get the following result from my query, basically I want to fetch all products and all attributes and for each product row display every attribute as a column.

I know I can "do" that with a `join`, but there is a lot of attributes and it simply isn't feasable to do something like that by hand so I want to do it dynamically but from SQL language instead of some external language.

Here is example of a resulting view/query:

```
id|Product name|att1 |att2 |...
-------------------------------
1 |Pro1        |val11|Null |...
2 |Pro2        |val21|val22|...
3 |...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just looking for a pivot query:

```
SELECT
    p.Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN a.Name = 'att1' THEN pa.value END) AS att1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN a.Name = 'att2' THEN pa.value END) AS att2
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN ProductAttribute pa
    ON p.id = pa.productId
LEFT JOIN Attributes a
    ON pa.attributeId = a.id
GROUP BY
    p.id, p.Name;
```

Comment: as I said, there is a lot of attributes and it's not feasable to write them out by hand.

Comment: Then you're going to need dynamic SQL, which SQLite does not support.  Then, you would need to write code to dynamically generate the query.

Comment: hm.. yes, that's what I feared. I was hoping there was some clever trick I'm not seeing.

Comment: Basically either you write a pivot query with hard coded columns, or you may write code which does this for you.